# Disappearing data in controller specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, database-cleaner

I have a really irritating problem with creating a simple controller spec with Rspec. Method causing trouble is called `#set_company` and it sets a parent 'account' for currently signed in user.

```
    def set_company
      return false if !user_signed_in?

      current_company = Company.find(current_user.company_id)
      set_current_tenant(current_company)
    end
```

My specs looks like that:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V3::UsersController, :type => :controller do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    let(:user)    { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:company) { user.company }

    before {
      allow(controller).to receive(:current_user)   {user}
      allow(controller).to receive(:current_tenant) {company}
    }

    it 'returns 200' do
      get :index
      expect(response.code.to_i).to eq 200
    end

    it 'assigns @users' do
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:users)).to eq [user]
    end
  end
end
```

The thing is, a second test is green but the first one is not (that order is correct!). It's red and that's because, when it gets triggered, there is no such thing as `company`. Here it is how it goes:

1. `user` is being created (with `company`, it's a dependency), IDs of that user is **1** and id of a company created with that user is also **1**
2. second test gets triggered and everything is great
3. first test gets triggered but there is no `Company` with ID=1 in the database, there is a new one with ID=2 which is obviously wrong and causes my `set_company` method to fall.

I think that might be related to the fact that i'm using database_cleaner but i have completely no idea how to deal with that and what can i do about it. Thank you all for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't yet have JavaScript-based tests, then there is no need for database_cleaner. As long as transactional fixtures are enabled, the data will be automatically cleared between each test.

Comment: Actually i do have some JS tests